# generate a jsf dataTable dynamically

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I need to create a jsf dataTable dynamically which means no of columns 
will vary and will be decided at run time
Any example will be appreciated.

-SPD

```
                        <ice:dataTable var="item"
                            value="#{section.rowDataModel}">
                            <ice:columns value="#{section.columnDataModel}"
                                var="column">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <ice:panelGroup>
                                        <ice:outputText value="#{column.columnName}" style="#{column.columnWidth}"/>
                                    </ice:panelGroup>
                                </f:facet>
                                <!-- display the table cell values-->
                                <ice:panelGroup
                                    style="text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <ice:inputText value="#{section.columnValue}" />
                                </ice:panelGroup>
                            </ice:columns>
                        </ice:dataTable>
```

Comment: Any effort on your part will also be appreciated.  This is not a code generation machine.

Comment: `QuestionNotFoundException`. Please specify a clear problem. At what point exactly are you struggling?

Comment: @Andrew:I asked for example code, could be an url which points me in right direction. I thought we are here for helping each other. BTW I resolved the issue.

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry for that,  Well I have a requirement to generate a jsf datatable based on the xml configuration( I have static xml file which has all the required data, I parse the xml and get the no of colums, I need to render), never know how many columns and rows we need to render.

Comment: @BlausC:I was wondering if there is any way to we can pass a columns list to a datatable. I got the solution. I added some piece of code below my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can bind a datatable:

```
<h:dataTable id="myTable" bind="#{myBean.table}"... />
```

Bean:

```
public class MyBean() {
   private HtmlDataTable dt;

   public MyBean() {
      initTable();
   }

   private initTable () {
      dt = new HtmlDataTable();
      //Add here your columns using HtmlColumn
      HtmlColumn hc = new HtmlColumn();

      //You can set colum values using ValueExpression
      //And add column to table using getChildren().add(hc);
      (...)
   }
  //Getters and setters
}
```

More info about ValueExpression can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html).

And feel free to use h:dataTable or rich:dataTable. Same for h:column or rich:column, just check the components name [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to nest c:forEach or ui:repeat (if you are using facelets) and render tr (outer loop),td (inner loop) tags yourself